# How to manage large product catalog in magento?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2, magento2.1

I am looking for a website Like **coverscart.com** using Magento. I have 2000 mobile covers for 500 model. I am trying to create configurable products, But it's not reliable solutions. Because for every model I have to create 2000 simple products.

With Configurable Total Catalog 1000000 :: 2000 Covers * 500 Model = 1000000

**It's not about the creating products, It's about managing the large product catalog.** Ref:: http://take.ms/goYoE

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: :Try check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180180/maximum-number-of-products-can-be-entered-into-website-on-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2 provide the functionality of auto created a number of associated product base on selected attributes.**

Like First, you have created one attribute for mobile model, Then you have wanted, enter 500 Model name only one time. Then after you have want to create one configurable product then select model attributes >> then click on Select All menu for all selected models >> Then create a configurable product.
Note: **automatically created 500 simple** (associated) product. Please see screenshot. http://prntscr.com/knsqxl

**Please check the example demo** : http://blankrefer.com/?http://demo-acm2.bird.eu/admin